# Unable to send mail using codeigniter & gmail though ssl enabled in php.ini

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail

I know this question has already been posted but I could not find the answer to my problem.
I'm using codeigniter to send an email, with gmail server. Here is the piece of code used for this task :

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['mail_path'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'my-email@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '******';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '30';
$config['mailtype'] = 'text';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['validate'] = TRUE;
$config['crlf'] = '\r\n';
$config['newline'] = '\n\n';

$this->load->library('email',$config);
$this->email->from('my-email@gmail.com');
$this->email->to('another-email');
$this->email->subject('Validation');

$message = "some message";

$this->email->message($message);

$this->email->send();
```

And i use `$this->email->print_debugger()` to show the errors.
Here are the messages I get :

```
The following SMTP error was encountered: 13 Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" -
did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:
from: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: RCPT TO:
to: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send data: DATA
data: 
The following SMTP error was encountered: ...
```

Of course, I uncommented the line corresponding to SSL in my php.ini file...

Any thoughts ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have openssl installed on your server?

Comment: i'm working local, on mac osx, with macports

Comment: i'm checking if the module is up to date, thanks

Comment: That didn't answer my question.

Comment: it is installed, i'm checking for updates

Comment: Is it loaded in PHP? Your error indicated that PHP doesn't know how to connect to secure connections which OpenSSL enables you too. But PHP should have the extension loaded too.

Comment: wow... now it's a timeout... you were right about the openssl extension. But now there is another prob. I'm gonna try to find out :)

Comment: Now the browser freezes. Nothing is written in CodeIgniter logs. Chrome console does not say anything... I don't know how to debug this :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a good tutorial on NetTuts about this subject.
Here is the link to it : http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-3/

The source code is downloadable.

Comment: thanks but i've all done that way and I think the problem is deeper... I have no error msg, the page is just frozen :(